# SEED data to mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I am looking for a script to seed data to mongo db document it contain as follows

`Class` table:

```
    _id:objectid
    name:string
    email:string
    student:objectID array
```

Here `class id` references the `student` table:

```
_id:objectID
classID:OBJECTid
subject :array
```

Answer (score 0):

if we want to seed data we can do this easily by just using bellow link
Click [here](https://json-generator.com/)
this tool help us to generate data and download them in Jason format